# Problems with Combobox MouseDown Events

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, event-handling

I have two Problems with the Mouse Events of `ComboBoxes`. What I want to achieve is a "Touch-and-Release"-Solution, that means after the User pressed/touched the `Combobox` for 500ms something should happen. I have `Class` where I fireup all my `Events` to my `Controls`. For the `Combobox`s I do it like this:

```
((ComboBox)obj).PreviewMouseDown -= CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Down;
                        ((ComboBox)obj).PreviewMouseDown += CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Down;
                        ((ComboBox)obj).PreviewMouseUp -= CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Up;
                        ((ComboBox)obj).PreviewMouseUp += CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Up;
```

My Up/Down-`Events` look like this:

```
private void CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _currentControl = (Control)sender;
        _touchHoldTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        _touchHoldTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        _touchHoldTimer.Tick += TouchHoldTimer_Tick;
        _touchHoldTimer.Start();           
    }

    private void CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _touchHoldTimer.Stop();
    }
```

The first Problem is, when my `Focus` is on another `Control` and click into the `Combobox` and hold, nothing happens. I first have to click into the `Combobox` and then click-and-hold and it works.

My second Problem is, that the `PreviewMouseDown` is also fired when the `Scrollbar` or `ToggleButton` of the `Combobox` is pressed. I tried something like this:

```
((ComboBox)obj).AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Down2));
                        ((ComboBox)obj).AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewMouseUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CTRLMouseButtonEventHandler_Up2));
```

But it didn' work. Can somebody point me in the reight direction please?

Answer (score 1):

Add another event. Set Event for hovering mouse over Combobox to give it selection. It would be same as clicking on it.

EDIT:

other possible events:

DropDownOpened
ContextMenuOpening

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_events(v=vs.110).aspx

2.
[KeyDown event is not firing when pressing enter in an UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193983/keydown-event-is-not-firing-when-pressing-enter-in-an-usercontrol)

Just replace enter with space.

Comment: Can't use the Hover/MouseEnter Solution

Comment: But hwo do they help me? I want the PreviewMouseDown to be fired as soon as I click into the `ComboBox` when my Focus is in another Control.

Comment: You can event for when mouse leave control to loose focus. That should work.